# Page content is covered by navigation bar

Tags: css, html, navigation

I have a navigation bar at the top of my page with a position of fixed, but the content that i want to have the below it ends up partialy covered by the navigation bar.

[Screenshot of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5c7A.png)

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Plus Graphing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        href="index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="all">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="header_container">
      <h1 class="heading"><b class="a_main">A+</b> Graphing</h1>

      <ul id="top_nav">

        <li class="nav_item"><a href="ourmission.html">Our Mission</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="rfloat"><a href="register_main.html">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="global_container">
      <b class="welcome">Welcome to <b class="a">A+</b> Graphing!</b>
      <div class="login_links">
        <a class="login_button" href="teacher_login.html">Teacher Login</a> <a class="login_button" href="student_login.html">Student Login</a>
      </div>
      <p class="intro_p">A+ Graphing is designed to introduce technology in the classroom and cut down teacher grading time.<br/>
        <a href="about.html">Learn More</a></p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer_container">
    A Harsh Mehta and Kevin Turner Production
    <div id="donate_main">
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
    ">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:`

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F2EEEE;
    height: 51px;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;

}
#all {
 height: 100%;
}

body a {
    color: red;

}
html {
height: 100%;
}
.a_main {
    color: red;
}

.heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.header_container {
    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

   width: 700px;
    height: 51px;
}


.header_teacher {
    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

   width: 1200px;
    height: 51px;
}

body ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

#top_nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;


}

#top_nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;

}

#top_nav li {

   display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;

}

#content {
    margin-top: 100px;

}

#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.global_container {
 position: absolute;
}

.welcome {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.a {
    color: red;
}



.login_button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.intro_p {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}


#donate_main {
    float: right;
}


.login {

}


#info_container {
    margin-bottom: 350px;
}
.login_links {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}

.footer_container {
margin-left: auto;
color:  grey;
border-top: 1px solid grey;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 700px;
}



.login_container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left:  -5em;
   margin-bottom: 350px;
   padding: 20px 50px 50px 30px;
}

.login_class {
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;   
}

.username {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}

.password {
     width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}

.username2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}

.password2 {
     width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}

.inline_info1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;

}

inline_info {
    float: left;  
}

.apple{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.student {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#register_content {

margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.main_inner {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.test_make {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

.list_item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 250px;
    width: 150px;
}


#quizes_main_list {
    width: 90%;
}

.inner_list{
   width: 100%;
}

.greeting_head {
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.view_quiz {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#quizes_main_list a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.quiz_item {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tests {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.tests a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.quiz_main {
    margin-top: 200px;

}

#main {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
}

.results_main {
    margin-top: 100px;
}


.score {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.results_green {
    color: green;
    font-size: 60px;
}

#question_stat {
    float: left;
}

#grades_main_list {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 90%;
}

.link_nav {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.link_inner {
color: white;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 15px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.global_content a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.inner_list {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.quiz_item {
    width: 100%;
}

.inline_info a{
    color: white;
}

.inline_info1 a{
    color: white;
}`
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a margin of top 0

This is from your code. Simply remove the line that says margin-top: 0;

```
#content {
    margin-top: 100px;

}

#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;  //remove this line
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But is there a way to do this without specifying a top margin for the content? Other sites that I see with navigation bars do no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through your code trying to find what caused this. Since you floated your header, I thought I could use `clear:both;` to fix it, but that didn't work.

For now, adding `margin-top:50px;` will do the trick.

```
#content{
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

I also added `z-index:10` to your header so it would stand in front of all of your content. I think it looks better ;)

```
#header{
  z-index:10;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9x8b/)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues. Can't recall where I finally saw the answer, but I fixed it by going to the storyboard and selecting the view controller in question, then selected the Attributes inspector. Under the View Controller section find Extend Edges and deselect Under Top Bars or Under Bottom Bars as needed. Don't know why these aren't deselected by default.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it.
Try changing the navigation bar's bottom margin to zero instead by adding the following.

```
.nav_bar {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

then add another class to deal with overflow

```
.clearfix::after{
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: table;
}
```

that should do the job.